# Two Phase Commit Rollback With PostgreSQL And Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Suppose I have Two Database db1 and bd2

db1 has a table tb1
db2 has a table tb2

now I want to insert a row to tb2 from tb1 and after successful insertion, the row will be deleted from tb1 so how i can do it using two-phase commit rollback in Postgres with node js